# Column label different from column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that holds positions and times.

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("2017-07-26 07:00:01", "2017-07-26 07:00:01", "2017-07-26 07:00:01", "2017-07-26 07:00:01", "2017-07-26 07:00:02", "2017-07-26 07:00:02"),
                 east = c(640348.4, 640348.8, 640348.9, 640348.7, 640348.7, 640348.8),
                 north = c(4858732.0, 4858732.0, 4858732.0, 4858732.2, 4858732.2, 4858732.2))

df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, tz = 'America/Chicago')
```

I made a function to calculate the distance between each point and a given reference point, and I add a column to the data frame to hold these calculated distances.

```
dist_fun <- function(p1, p2) {sqrt((p2[1]-p1[1])^2 + (p2[2] - p1[2])^2)}

reference_pt <- c(640342.7, 4858714.1)
names(reference_pt) <- c('east', 'north')

df$dist <- dist_fun(df[, c('east', 'north')], reference_pt)
```

My desired outcome is pretty obviously a data frame with four columns, named `time`, `east`, `north`, and `dist`:

```
                 time     east     north        dist
1 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.4 4858732.0 18.78563281
2 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.8 4858732.0 18.91084345
3 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.9 4858732.0 18.94333656
4 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.7 4858732.2 19.06856051
5 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.7 4858732.2 19.06856051
6 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.8 4858732.2 19.10026178
```

However, the output I'm getting is

```
                 time     east     north        east
1 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.4 4858732.0 18.78563281
2 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.8 4858732.0 18.91084345
3 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.9 4858732.0 18.94333656
4 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.7 4858732.2 19.06856051
5 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.7 4858732.2 19.06856051
6 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.8 4858732.2 19.10026178
```

For some reason the last column is named `east`, even though I defined it as `df$dist`! To fix it is not just a simple name change, because when I check the names of the data frame..

```
names(df)
[1] "time"  "east"  "north" "dist"
```

So why is the column headed with `east` and not `dist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your function returns a data.frame, and the data.frame has a column name associated with it from your operations.

I'd recommend doing it more like this:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(dist = sqrt((reference_pt[1] - east)^2 + (reference_pt[2] - north)^2))

                 time     east   north     dist
1 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.4 4858732 18.78563
2 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.8 4858732 18.91084
3 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.9 4858732 18.94334
4 2017-07-26 07:00:01 640348.7 4858732 19.06856
5 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.7 4858732 19.06856
6 2017-07-26 07:00:02 640348.8 4858732 19.10026
```

If you'd rather do it with the function, it'll work like this:

```
dist_fun <- function(p1, p2) { 
    distCalc <- sqrt((p2[1]-p1[1])^2 + (p2[2] - p1[2])^2)
    names(distCalc) <- "dist"
    return(distCalc)
}

df <- cbind(df, dist_fun(df[, c('east', 'north')], reference_pt))
```

Also note that your original operations create a data.frame within a data.frame:

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ time : POSIXct, format: "2017-07-26 07:00:01" "2017-07-26 07:00:01" "2017-07-26 07:00:01" "2017-07-26 07:00:01" ...
 $ east : num  640348 640349 640349 640349 640349 ...
 $ north: num  4858732 4858732 4858732 4858732 4858732 ...
 $ dist :'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ east: num  18.8 18.9 18.9 19.1 19.1 ...
```

Which can cause problems with other operations if you don't realize you have a nested object.